# This AWS Lambda Function to Get Data From PHP URL doesn't return a value

Tags: php, json, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm working on an `AWS Lambda function` in `Node.js` to call a `PHP`

> URL

that will return a JSON encoded response so that Alexa (Amazon Dot, etc.) can reply to a user query.  I've got all my intents set up properly and Alexa (online test) replies to the question, but the  tag contains "Unchanged" (see code), indicating it isn't getting anything from the `http.get()` function in `Node.js`.

Here's the function to get the text that Alexa should speak:

function getData(mypath) {

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
host: 'www.gypsysticks.com',
port: 80,
path: mypath
};
var mydata = "Unchanged";
http.get(options, function(res) {
    res.on("response", function(chunk) {
        mydata = chunk;
    });
});
return mydata;
```

}

I'm building this "Skill" for Alexa for my band, Gypsy Sticks. Currently the url and path points to [www.gypsysticks.com/echo/tonight.php](http://www.gypsysticks.com/echo/tonight.php) which is supposed to return the location and time of the show for tonight.  Right now I've just got it returning a `JSON` string with `{ "response" : "Test Success" }`

I'm not familiar with `Node.js`, or the `http.get()` function.

Comment: Your callback (`function(res) {}`) is asynchronous, which means `return mydata;` is called before the response is ever handled.

Comment: Thanks! At least now I understand why it's not working. I still don't have a clue how to accomplish the task at hand. I'll keep trying. And again, I sincerely appreciate the help.